# Merging two dataframes, with different lengths, and repeating values

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes with the same col 'A' that I want to merge on. However, in df2 col A is replicated a random number of times. This replication is important to my problem and I cannot drop it. I want the final dataframe to look like df3. Where Col A merges Col B values to each replication.

```
df1                       df2
Col A   Col B             Col A    Col B
1       v                 1        a
2       w                 2        b    
3       x                 2        c
4       y                 3        d
                          3        e
                          4        f

df3
Col A    Col B    Col C
1        a        v
2        b        w
2        c        w
3        d        x
3        e        x
4        f        y
```

Answer (score 1):

Use merge:

```
df2.merge(df1, on='Col A')
Out: 
   Col A Col B_x Col B_y
0      1       a       v
1      2       b       w
2      2       c       w
3      3       d       x
4      3       e       x
5      4       f       y
```

And if necessary, rename afterwards:

```
df = df2.merge(df1, on='Col A')
df.columns = ['Col A', 'Col B', 'Col C']
```

for more info, see the Pandas Documentation on [merging and joining](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series` created by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
print (df1.set_index('Col A')['Col B'])
Col A
1    v
2    w
3    x
4    y
Name: Col B, dtype: object

df2['Col C'] = df2['Col A'].map(df1.set_index('Col A')['Col B'])
print (df2)
   Col A Col B Col C
0      1     a     v
1      2     b     w
2      2     c     w
3      3     d     x
4      3     e     x
5      4     f     y
```

Comment: oh man... this may not be "wrong" but it really is a hard answer for a learner to grok. I think `merge` or `join` are much more approachable

Comment: @JDLong - Yes, it is another solution. But I prefer `map` if need join only one column, because faster

Comment: Yes, exactly. I think run time.